# Building Gold linker in FreeBSD

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, freebsd, binutils

I followed the steps on http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html#lto-how-to-build to build the gold plugin on FreeBSD but !

Heres a link to the screenshot of the error:http://postimg.org/image/anlpuufbl/

This is the error message that it shows and so I am also unable to get ld-new.
I checked and no CFLAGS were set in etc/make.conf.

How to proceed with the installation?
I am using the deault clang version supplied with FreeBSD 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

You may need `LDFLAGS=-fuse-ld=gold -flto` in /etc/make.conf

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to install [devel/binutils port](http://www.freshports.org/devel/binutils/) or its package. It contains gold linker under `ld.gold` name, which should work with LLVM plugin.